# How to use multiple external libraries with dart:ffi?

Tags: c, flutter, dart, yaml, ffi

I want to use multiple external libraries using Flutter's `dart:ffi`.
Using `openssl` and `net-snmp` library files.
When placing multiple external libraries in the root folder of flutter, is it correct to place only the src folder in the root folder?

**pattern-one**

root(folder)-src(folder)-API call C code-libcrypto.so(dll)
-API call C code-libssl.so(dll)
-Etc...

**pattern-two**

root(folder)-src_openssl(folder)-API call C code-libcrypto.so(dll)
-API call C code-libssl.so(dll)
-Etc...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38dES.png)

***current situation***

You can only specify the root folder's src folder in the `pubspec.yaml` definition.

If you specify a folder other than the `src` folder of the root folder in the `pubspec.yaml` definition, an error will occur when executing the `flutter pub get` command.

```
 ffi_openssl_api:
     path: ../
```

I want to use an external library on Windows platform, Linux platform, MacOS platform, but I don't have a technical sample.